# [].slice.call vs Array.prototype.slice.call

Tags: javascript, performance

I have been wondering recently.

I have in the past used `[].slice.call` or `[].forEach.call` .... etc
I thought doing it this way was great because it makes it easy to turn something array like, into an array easily.

However, then I started thinking about it and it would be better to do something like this:
`Array.prototype.slice.call` or `Array.prototype.forEach.call` instead.

Am I correct in thinking that this has much better performance for the following reasons:

1. `[].slice.call` would create a blank array, then access the arrays prototype and would need to be garbage collected later on.
2. `Array.prototype.slice.call` would call the Array prototype method directly, and would not first create a blank array and then traverse the prototype tree.

Is there anything I have missed? also is there anything I am missing, such as a reason why in some cases [] would be better than Array.prototype?

Comment: Two standard replies. First, this is not your bottleneck. Second, time it; I have no idea which is faster.

Comment: I suspect the main reason some people like `[]` is just because it's shorter.

Comment: @Barmar That was why I liked it in the first place :)

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: What is the point to call slice on an empty array?

Comment: I would not use `[].slice.call`  but e.g. store the `Array.prototype.slice`  in a local `var`. The reason why I wouldn't use  `[].slice.call` is because it creates a object that is never used, even  though it most likely would not have noticeable performance impacts.

Comment: @JulienFouilhé `Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments-or-whatever )` is a common pattern to convert array-like objects (as arguments on functions), to *"true"* Arrays.

Comment: @laconbass Thank you, I have never been interested in doing that, but this could be useful someday.

Comment: Doesn't really matter, both will make your function run 100000x slower compared to converting arguments in a loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Please refer to existing benchmarks

Like [this one on jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/array-prototype-slice-call-vs-slice-call) I found [typing "`[].slice performance" on google](https://www.google.es/search?es_sm=94&q=Array.prototype.slice+performance&oq=Array.prototype.slice+performance&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.0.6788.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..43.serp..0.0.0.dfF_GZ01pis).

[Revision 15 of the same benchmark](http://jsperf.com/array-prototype-slice-call-vs-slice-call/15) also provides a wide variety of approaches, while [revision 12](http://jsperf.com/array-prototype-slice-call-vs-slice-call/15) was also interesting for me.

### What code to use

As @Barmar pointed out on comments, `[].slice.call` *is shorter* than `Array.prototype.slice.call`, so it's pretty common to see the former.

As @t.niese pointed out on comments, `[].slice.call` *creates a object that is never used, even though it most likely would not have noticeable performance impacts*.

IMHO, if worried about performance, I prefer creating a shortcut with `bind` on an outer scope and then use it, instead *shortcuting* `Array.prototype.slice.call` with `[].slice.call`:

```js
var slice = Function.prototype.call.bind( Array.prototype.slice );

// and then just

function doSomething( ){
    slice( arguments );
    slice( arguments, 1, -1 );
}

slice( whatever );
slice( whatever, 0, 3 );

// and so on
```

### Conclusions

Definitely, as seen on benchmarks, performance is not the same.

When performance **really** matters, just benchmark your code to optimize it according to your requeriments.

When performance does not matter enought to worry about a small improvement like this one, it's a code style related decision, so pick your personal preference or follow the code style guide of the project you are working at.

#### Side note

@Barmar posted a link on comments about [Premature Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) really interesting too.

Comment: Thats a strange test: `_slcall = [].slice.call`. This will result in an `undefined is not a function error for the _slcall(items); test`

Comment: @t.niese Yeah, revision 15 is a bit crazy. Revision 1 is just fine to feed OP's curiosity.

Comment: @laconbass I knew that `Array.prototype` should be quicker and have come across the jsperf before. Just wanted to know if there was something blindingly obvious I have overlooked or just didnt know.
I want to be a javascript developer so I want to know everything :)

Comment: In that case refer to @t.niese 's comment on the question. I've updated my answer as I think it's a useful tip an agree with that assertion, plus added my personal thoughts about this topic because I also researched about that time ago.

Comment: If a `var slice = Array.prototype.slice;  slice.call(items);` is faster/slower then your `bind` example (which also looks nice), mainly depends on the js engine itself. But anyway if using one of them results in a bottleneck then there is most likely a bigger problem with the program/workflow itself (after converting the array-like to an array object the data is also used for something and this step normally takes much more time then the _converting step_).

Comment: @t.niese I totally agree with you

Comment: @laconbass Thanks for the Answer :) it did bring about some good discussion, would be great for anyone else who happens to find the question!

Comment: Seeing as jsperf is no longer a thing and that this is the first Google search result, could you please update your comment?

Comment: @DerekZiemba I see it's 5xx. Will the site be shutdown?

Comment: jsperf hasn't been accessible for some time now, I wanna say years.  Surprisingly the site now returns `500: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR`.  Which is actually an improvement, before you wouldn't even get a response.